# Need inputs in architecting SOA which handles multiple versions of schema

Tags: wcf

I am working on an assignment where building SOA for an existing application. I am trying to get input from you guys on which is better approach for the SOA application:

**Here is the requirement**:

We want to develop SOA application that helps other vendors to integrate with our system. I also understand for some clients we need to bring new fields to support the integration.

**Solution Needed**: Looking for either one SOA application which can handle all the clients to do the integration with our system. Question Is it possible to do so? Because we might have different contracts possibly bringing new fields coming into the contracts.

(or) Develop a another SOA service if the service contract changes and have a front gate SOA service to divert the call to the appropriate SOA services based on the version [Probably mentioned in the SOAP header].

If anyone of you guys have handled this type of requirement and know how to handle this problem, that would help me.

Thanks,

Nazim

Comment: Before you decide to use WCF, I strongly recommend you think it through. Consider some examples of the scenarios - handling different versions; handling customization, etc. You may find you have a bigger problem than how to develop the SOA technology.

Answer (score 1):

Nazim,

if I'm understanding your problem correctly, you are looking to create a WCF service that supports [**versioning**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx).  You have a few choices: you can either keep creating new services if the clients can't handle lax versioning, or modify the data contracts (by implementing the [`IExtensibleDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx) interface).  In either case, make sure you check out the [**Best Practices**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491124.aspx).
It describes the two approaches you identified.

It basically comes down to determining if you prefer to implement and maintain what you call the 'front gate', which can become a headache when you have lot of supported versions, or publish all versions of the services side-to-side. You would then either manually tell your clients to interact with a specific endpoint, or use some web service registry application that would handle this for you.